# How to use python module timeago with flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use python timeago module to convert datetime to "some time ago" in my flask application. I am looking solution to convert date while getting results from my model or while processing in template...

I did some research in google but didnt find any useful cases related to flask...

**sample code**

```
class SampleModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "sample_table"
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name =db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    location=db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    arrival_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, id:int):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=id).order_by(cls.arrival_date.desc()).all()
```

**flasktemplate**

```
<div>
{% for row in page_data %}
     .
     .
     .
     <td>{{ row["arrival_date"]  }}</td>
     .
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

while inserting data to the table it should take actual timestamp but while printing into template it should use timeago...

also thought to use init method in Model class, but confused with implementation...

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create filter function for your jinja templates

```py
    @app.template_filter('timeago')
    def fromnow(date):
        return timeago.format(date, datetime.datetime.now())
```

In templates you use it like this:

```html
<div>
    {{some_date|timeago}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The document shows [this](https://pypi.org/project/timeago/) which you can include in your route, and pass it along with the render template:

```
import timeago, datetime

now = your date
date = datetime.datetime.now() 

print (timeago.format(date, now)) # will print 3 minutes ago
```

But in your case you need to use use it in html itself :
I would recommend to use Flask-Moment in that case along with moment.js. A snippet of the code can be found [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xii-dates-and-times).

Comment: if it is one record i could have done that. if you see my model, it returns bulk records...

Comment: seems like Flask-Moment will resolve my issue. Thanks for the response....

Answer (score 1):

There is a flask module available -> Flask-Humanize.

https://github.com/vitalk/flask-humanize

This module will help you to convert lots of stuffs to human readable format, also supports for multiple language...

**this is how we initialize in app.**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_humanize import Humanize

app = Flask(__name__)
humanize = Humanize(app)

@humanize.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return 'ru_RU'
```

**this is how we use it in template**

```
{{ datetime.datetime.now()|humanize('naturalday') }} -> today
{{ datetime.date(2014,4,21)|humanize('naturaldate') }} -> Apr 21 2014
{{ (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1))|humanize() }} -> an hour ago
```